# How can I change the default drag and drop action on a folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste, drag-and-drop

I have a special folder which I always drag and drop many files to. How can I change the default "Copy to" action to be "Move to"?

This is what I mean:

[image]

[image]

I know I can do it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> but I want to change the default action to avoid making mistakes.

Comment: Ctrl=Copy, Shift=Move <-- thanks for that tip.  But shift AFTER you click to drag.  Shift clicking on one file when another is already selected, selects a bunch of files, which could be inadvertently moved.

Comment: You can change the default drop effect using the registry. Value name [`DefaultDropEffect`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507001/is-there-a-registry-setting-i-can-change-to-make-the-default-drag-and-drop-to-mo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by mapping the folder as a separate drive, that way causing the "copy default" behaviour when dragging to that folder.

This can be done on the command line using `subst`:

```
subst <driveletter> <folder path>
```

Or you download and use Visual Subst.

I've tested it out (using the command line), and it does seem to work (giving the default drag-and-drop copy effect).

I haven't tried Visual Subst, but saw it mentioned online. The only advantage they mention is that it allows you to ask it to remap the drive on startup, but you can achieve this easily using the command line, by putting the command in a script and placing in the `Startup` folder.

**EDIT for persistence:**

A different/better way to achieve a persistent mapping, at least in Windows 8/10 (maybe other versions as well), is using `regedit`:

```
1) Open start menu.
2) Type `regedit` and press enter.
3) Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Session Manager > DosDevices
4) Add a new string value with the key "<driveletter>:" (e.g. "P:")
5) Double click on it to enter the data value "\??\<folder path>" (e.g. "\??\C:\DragFolder")
6) Might need to reboot for it to take effect.
```

**WARNING**: Always be careful with regedit. Don't change anything you don't know what does, or it could break *everything*.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default behaviour of the drag and drop with *Drag'n'Drop Editor*

I just tried it and works perfectly. Uninstallation of the tweak also works. My OS is Windows 7 64 SP1.

https://winaero.com/dragndrop-editor/

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no way of changing that behaviour.

If you drag & drop files without pressing any key and both locations are on the same drive, it should move it by default.

[If files are on different drives, then it should copy by default.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Move-and-copy-files-using-drag-and-drop)

You can continue using <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you do now, or drag & drop with your right button, which will give you the right-click menu.

Another way to do this is [adding `Copy to` and/or `Move to` to the contextual](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/516-context-menu-add-copy-folder-move-folder.html) menu.

Or adding options to the `Send to` menu. I haven't tried this one, but you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-locations-to-the-windows-7-send-to-menu.html).